# How to merge similar HSL colors together by a specific amount

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am looking for a way to merge similar hsl colors together by a specific amount. Let's say I have the following three colors: `150, 50, 100`, `149, 49, 100`, `151, 51, 99`. The result I am looking for should be a single value: `150, 50, 100`.

Let me try to explain it better:

**Example Data:**

```
const colors = {
  red: [
    {h:151 , s:57 , l:100},
    {h:150 , s:5 , l:100},
    {h:155 , s:50 , l:100},
    {h:125 , s:100 , l:100},
    {h:132 , s:0 , l:100},
  ],
  green: [...],
  blue: [...]
}
```

Now let's say each array contains a lot of items, and I want to reduce the number of items by merging similar items together. The threshold must be a variable. The merging process is simply taking the average of all similar items.

I hope that my explanation is clear, it is quite hard to explain.

Comment: Can we have a look of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @AyazShah The thing is, I am not even sure how to think about this problem. If I am simply looping through the array, I need to check it's value, compare to each other item of the array. So I guess a two-dimensional loop is required. Is this the right way of thinking?

Comment: it is called [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can use as a start. What it does :

Ignore a value, if there are already a value that is matching `(using threshold system)`;

What you want to do is very specific, so start with understanding this, then adapt it to your need. In case of **coding** trouble, we will help you.

Actually in here, we shouldn't **create** your code, but help you with **yours**. I feel in a good mood

```js
const colors = {
  red: [{
      h: 151,
      s: 57,
      l: 100
    },
    {
      h: 150,
      s: 5,
      l: 100,
    },
    {
      h: 155,
      s: 50,
      l: 100,
    },
    {
      h: 125,
      s: 100,
      l: 100,
    },
    {
      h: 132,
      s: 0,
      l: 100,
    },
  ],
};

const tresholdH = 10;
const tresholdS = 100;
const tresholdL = 100;

function reduceArrayByTreshold(array) {
  return array.reduce((tmp, x) => {
    if (tmp.some(({
          h,
          s,
          l,
        }) => (x.h >= h - tresholdH && x.h <= h + tresholdH) &&
        (x.s >= s - tresholdS && x.s <= s + tresholdS) &&
        (x.l >= l - tresholdL && x.l <= l + tresholdL))) {
      return tmp;
    }

    return [
      ...tmp,
      x,
    ];
  }, []);
}

const colorsReduced = Object.keys(colors).reduce((tmp, x) => {
  tmp[x] = reduceArrayByTreshold(colors[x]);

  return tmp;
}, {});

console.log(colorsReduced);
```

Comment: You have no idea, how much you just helped me. Thank you so much.